# How to rename list objects in self defined function?

Tags: r, list, function, double-quotes, single-quotes

```
quote <- function(namefoo, namebar){
  set.seed(3)
  foo <- rnorm(n = 5)
  bar <- rnorm(n = 5)
  return(list(namefoo=foo,namebar=bar))
}
```

From the above function, If I ran `quote(test, test1)` the name of the two objects in the list remain as `namefoo` and `namebar` instead of what I specified in the function call.

If I just ran the code seperately as:

```
set.seed(3)
foo <- rnorm(n = 5)
bar <- rnorm(n = 5)
obj <- list(test=foo,test1=bar)
```

Then obj will return `foo` and `bar` with the amended names. How do I make my function do this? I've tried several combinations of including quotes as well, from the function call to the function itself but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

One way is this:

```
quote <- function(namefoo, namebar){
  set.seed(3)
  foo <- rnorm(n = 5)
  bar <- rnorm(n = 5)
  out <- list(foo, bar)
  names(out) <- c(namefoo, namebar)
  out
}
```

You can save the list to a variable and then name the elements with `names`.

```
# quote('foo', 'bar')
# $namefoo
# [1] -0.9619334 -0.2925257  0.2587882 -1.1521319
# [5]  0.1957828
# 
# $namebar
# [1]  0.03012394  0.08541773  1.11661021
# [4] -1.21885742  1.26736872
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a very bad idea to name your function `quote`, a very important `R` function is named just like that.

Use `setNames` :

```
fun <- function(namefoo, namebar){
  set.seed(3)
  foo <- rnorm(n = 5)
  bar <- rnorm(n = 5)
  setNames(list(foo,bar),c(namefoo, namebar))
}

fun("hi","there")
# $hi
# [1] -0.9619334 -0.2925257  0.2587882 -1.1521319  0.1957828
# 
# $there
# [1]  0.03012394  0.08541773  1.11661021 -1.21885742  1.26736872
```

You might also see this kind of code around too, using more advanced features of `rlang` / `tidyverse` :

```
library(tidyverse)
fun2 <- function(namefoo, namebar){
  set.seed(3)
  foo <- rnorm(n = 5)
  bar <- rnorm(n = 5)
  lst(!!namefoo := foo,!!namebar := bar)
}

fun2("hi","there")
# $hi
# [1] -0.9619334 -0.2925257  0.2587882 -1.1521319  0.1957828
# 
# $there
# [1]  0.03012394  0.08541773  1.11661021 -1.21885742  1.26736872
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do

```
quotefn <- function(...) {
        nm <- c(...)
        out <- replicate(length(nm), rnorm(n = 5), simplify = FALSE)
        names(out) <- nm
        out}
quotefn("foo", "bar")
#$foo
#[1] -0.5784837 -0.9423007 -0.2037282 -1.6664748 -0.4844551

#$bar
#[1] -0.74107266  1.16061578  1.01206712 -0.07207847 -1.13678230
```